# How can I adjust the UITableViewCell height to the content of UITextView that's inside?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

In my story board I have a `UITableView` with dynamically generated `UITableViewCell`s. Each cell contains 2 labels and 1 text view:

[image]

I have a code that adjust the size of the textfield to the amount of text:

```
let fixedWidth = cell.myComment.frame.size.width
cell.myComment.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
let newSize = cell.myComment.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
var newFrame = cell.myComment.frame
newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
cell.myComment.frame = newFrame;
```

and it works fine, when I set a background color of my textView to red I see:

[image]

and the cell itself - I'm setting the size in here:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
     if indexPath.row == 0 {
         return 100//this is my static cell
     }
     else {
         return 117; //for now it's hardcoded - how can I set this value dynamically based on content?
     }
}
```

So as I wrote in the comment above - how can I set the height of the cell dynamically based on the amount of text in the text view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to getting self-sizing table cells (autolayout-based, which I recommend) is as follows:

- Add your subviews to the `contentView` of the `UITableViewCell`
- Provide constraints between your subviews and the `contentView` such that your subviews reach all edges of the table cell. In your case, this probably means aligning the `leading`, `trailing`, `top`, and `bottom` edges of your `UITextView` to the corresponding edges of the `contentView`.
- Set the row height to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` instead of a hardcoded `CGFloat`.
- Somewhere in your controller, provide an estimation of the height with `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = x` (a hard coded constant is fine, this is for performance).

Comment: Hm, so by doing so, do I still need part of the code responsible for adjusting the height of text view?

Comment: Nope. As long as you constrain the edges, UITextView is smart enough to wrap the text onto the second line. It, like `UILabel`, has an intrinsic content size based on its text.