# Swift - autoresize UiTableViewCell to fit content

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm using Swift 2.3 and I have a TableView in which I would like that each row automatically resize to fit its content.

In my Main.storyboard if I set row height to 120 I have that the first row is correct but not the second one:

[image]

But if I set row height to 190 I have the second row correct but not the first one:

[image]

I can have different content in each row so I don't want to set static row height but I would like that each row automatically fit its size to content.

Can you help me to find a solution?

I read other posts that suggest to add:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
```

`self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

But I get this error:
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'

I don't why..

Comment: check out the problem I raised couple days ago, maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671444/how-can-i-adjust-the-uitableviewcell-height-to-the-content-of-uitextview-thats

Comment: I've tried but the estimatedRowHeight lead me to the exception "Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint" so I removed it from code.

Comment: Ahh! ok, I resolved. I got the exception because I didn't add the bottom constraits of the content view of the cell. Resolved this exception I've followed your link and I resolved completely. Thank you!